# Difference of STL behaviour between c++ threads and Linux clone

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, stl

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
#define CLONE

mutex m;

int subproc(void*){
    cout << "Start" << endl;
    while(true){
        vector<int>V;
        //m.lock();
        V.reserve(10);
        //m.unlock();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            V.push_back(i);
    }
}

int main(){
    const unsigned int proc_num = 4;
    const unsigned int stack_size = 16*1024*1024;

    #if defined CLONE
        for(int i=0;i<proc_num;i++)
            clone(subproc, new char[stack_size]+stack_size, CLONE_VM, nullptr);
    #elif defined THREADS
        vector<thread>Vec;
        for(int i=0;i<proc_num;i++)
            Vec.push_back(thread(subproc, nullptr));
    #endif

    while(true)
        sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code with different #defines (`CLONE` or `THREADS`), program behaves differently. With `CLONE`, child processes immediately crash (address sanitizer gives `heap-use-after-free` error). When I use `THREADS`, everything works as expected.
If I remove comments from mutexes, both versions work well, so the problem is about allocating memory for vector.

Why is that so? And is there a method to make CLONE version work (condition is that all processes should share memory)?

Comment: Unrelated: Avoid `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` (rational: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and `using namespace std;` (rational: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Definitely avoid using them together as they amplify one another's worst aspects.

Comment: Unfortunately, I will have to use both of them in my final application. Never mind why.

Comment: Getting back to this (now that I have a handy dandy Linux box at my disposal) and I can't duplicate. Will take another look at it from home.